# Update iOS on jailbroken iPhone 5S with evasi0n7 *without USB*

Tags: wifi, ios, jailbreak, iphone

I jailbreaked my iPhone 5S with evasi0n7 [iOS 7.0.4] a few months ago.
The thing is, that I accidently broke my USB driver on the iPhone (I can still charge the phone but not connect it to any USB data port).

I want to update my iPhone to iOS 8 and delete the Jailbreak. The problem is, that I cannot use iTunes to update, because the USB connection doesn't work. I already made a backup of all personal data using SSH/SFTP and WiFi.

Do you know how to update my iPhone to iOS8? (The problem is that evasi0n is somehow preventing the Phone to show the Update in the `Settings > General`-tab)

Edit: I also used `Settings > General > Reset > "Erase all Content and Settings"` but it just got stuck and booted up with the evasi0n7 still installed

Comment: I'll just add that evasi0n7 blocks that because they move files, and updating messes with the jailbreak process. Same with "Erase all Content and Settings" -- I'm suprised your phone restarted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could somehow manage to fix the problem using the tool `Cydia Eraser` (aka `Cydia Impactor`), which removed my the Jailbreak and allowed me to install the newest iOS version.

The Tool can be found here:
http://www.ios9cydia.com/cydia-eraser.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to be able to connect the device to a computer over USB to restore iOS.

Comment: Could i maybe extract a .ipsw file and transfer it to my iPhone so that I can update the OS manually?

Or do I have to go to an apple store so that they can reset my phone completely?

Comment: @Unknown You can't restore iOS on an iOS device—it requires a computer. An Apple Store will do the same to restore iOS, but when it fails, they will ask you whether the device is jailbroken and will not help any further as your answer will be yes.